# Dynamic Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

```
int[] array = new int[scan.nextInt()];
```

I found this code online and don't understand it.  I think it dynamically creates an array.  Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: It creates an array with the size specified by the next console input.

Comment: Java does not have dynamic arrays, where "dynamic" means the size is variable at runtime.  This is a statically sized array whose size is specified by user input.  After it's created its size is constant and cannot be changed.

Comment: @Jim Garrison The array size will be defined at runtime (the user input must be at runtime).
Java doesn't have a dynamic arrays, but thats what happenning behind the scenes.

Comment: No, the array is being allocated at runtime with a size that is read in.  That is not the meaning of "dynamic array".

Comment: Oh, okay.  Thanks everyone.  I thought it would add to the array whatever Int was entered, regardless of how many.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array = new int[scan.nextInt()];
```

is equivalent to the following code snippet.

```
int size = scan.nextInt();
int[] array = new int[size];
```

The code snippet creates an array with the size given as an input by the user. You can check it by printing the length of the array.

```
System.out.println(array.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array = new int[scan.nextInt()];
```

***int*** -  is the type of elements that will be contained within the array.

***[ ]*** -  indicates that it's an array.

***array*** -  reference to the array object.

***new*** - creates the array object.

***scan.nextInt()*** - scans the next token of the input as an int and sets the array length to that value.